# Uniform convergence of telescoping series

Tags: calculus

find if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(nxe^{-nx^2} - (n-1)xe^{-(n-1)x^2} \right)$$ uniformly converges in [0,1].

Let $$a_n = nxe^{-nx^2}$$

and let $S_k(x)$ be the partial sum such that
$$S_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k a_n - a_{n-1} = a_k- a_1 = a_k - 0 = kxe^{-kx^2} = \frac {kx} {e^{kx^2}}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) = ~? $$

maybe the series doesn't uniformly converges at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $S_k(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$.

The sequence $x_k = 1/\sqrt{k}$ is in $[0,1]$, but $S_k(x_k)= kx_k/e^{kx_k^2}=\sqrt{k}/e$ does not converge to $0$.

Also

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\frac{kx}{e^{kx^2}}\right| = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{2}e^{1/2}} \neq 0$$

Hence, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: isn't the sup test requires $sup_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|$?

Comment: You converted the sequence of partial sums into the sequence we are now testing for uniform convergence

Comment: The series converges pointwise to zero but the sup of the sequence of partial sums does not , so nonuniform convergence

Comment: $S_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, but $sup|S_n(x)-S(x)| = sup|S_n(x)|$ does not converge to $0$.